# How to handle dynamically variable no. of parameters in java?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, direction

The request to get the route directions from google api is as follows.

```
DirectionsApi.newRequest(getGeoContext())
                    .mode(TravelMode.DRIVING)
                    .origin(origin)
                    .destination(destination)
                    .waypoints(getWaypointsString(waypoints))
                    .departureTime(now)
                    .optimizeWaypoints(true)
                    .await();
```

The .waypoints is a method with variable number of parameters:

```
public DirectionsApiRequest waypoints(java.lang.String... waypoints)
```

Now my problem is that I will have to update my route dynamically and with that, the number of waypoints in my route may vary. I can handle this manually like :

```
.waypoints(Latlng1)
.waypoints("Latlng1","Latlng2")
```

Anyway i can write a generic method for this or how to handle it if i dont know how many waypoints would i get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `...` notation is just a hidden way to pass an array.
So actually inside `waypoints` method you have a parameter `java.lang.String[] waypoints`, whis is an array. So, you can find out its length and read its elements one by one:

```
public DirectionsApiRequest waypoints(java.lang.String... waypoints) {
   int numOfWayPoints = waypoints.length;
   for (int i = 0 ; i < numOfWayPoints ; i++) {
      doSomethingWithTheWayPoint(waypoints[i]);
   }
   // or
   for (java.lang.String waypoint : waypoints) {
      doSomethingWithTheWayPoint(waypoint);
   }
}
```

to call such a method you can do it in the reverse: simply pass an array as the last parameter:

```
   java.lang.String[] waypoints = {"Ltlng1", "Ltlng2"}; // fill the array
   .... 
   .waypoints(waypoints); // call the method, passing the array instead of a list of parameters

   // or
   ArrayList<java.lang.String> waypointsList = new ArrayList<>();
   waypointsList.add("Ltlng1");
   waypointsList.add("Ltlng2"); 
   // etc
   .... 
   .waypoints(waypointsList.toArray(new java.lang.String[])); // call the method, passing the array of strings obtained from a list
```